# How to create object in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to use Custom post type to create object in my website. Object would hold: title, picture, color of the object and identifier (Something similar to "cache" in geocaching.com). Are these parameters created as taxonomy, custom fields or supports?

Comment: `Object` in which sense ?

Answer (score 1):

The rule of the thumb is following: term of taxonomy is something *group* of posts shares, custom field is something *individual* post has.

Depending on exact context and requirements things might be better saved as one or another. For example *group* of posts might share general color (term), but if you want each post to have *exact unique shade* of color then it's better as custom field with that data.

So I would guess your items break down as following:

- title — native title
- picture — native post thumbnail or custom field with attachment ID
- color — might go different ways as above
- identifier — custom field

Comment: Thanks for answer. One thing I did not understand - I want the custom post type a color so that I could filter them out later. For example create map to display those post and add filter of colours. So I would create red, green and blue taxonomy. But I would also like to add size - small, medium , big. That would give me 6 taxonomies but I want them to be as 2 characters of my custom post type - size and color. How do I group taxonomies in order to distinct them from each other?

Comment: Red, green, blue will be _terms_ of Color _taxonomy_. Small, medium, big will be _terms_ of Size _taxonomy_. So you only need _two_ taxonomies (Color and Size) and each can have as many terms (differens colors and different sizes respectively) in it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Those would be custom fields. I'd recommend using the Custom Post Type UI plugin, but you can do this manually in functions.php as well.